# pull data from 16 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with 18 tables and i need to pull data from 16 of them, the query i used doesn't generate any errors but i get an empty set message, there is data in all the tables, and I'm using the basic method of joins. can anyone suggest to me if this will be possible and if i can accomplish this with a basic query or i need to do some type of union or sub query?

thanks mates

Here is a look at the query

```
SELECT student.stuId, student.stuFName, student.stuLName,
student.stuGender, student.stuMarSt, student.stuDOB,
student.stuAge, student.stuAddress, student.stuTown,
student.stuCountry, student.stuNation, student.stuEmail, 
student.stuPhone, student.stuAccType, student.stuAccNo, 
student.stuNISNo, student.stuBIRNo, student.stuBCPIN, 
student.stuPPNO, student.stuIDNO, student.stuDPNO, 
student.stuDA, student.verified, student.eduId, 
student.bankId, student.contId, student.courseId, 
student.courseId2, student.centreId, student.registrationDate,
bank.bankId, bank.bankName, bank.bankAddress, centre.centreId, 
centre.centreName, personalother.contId, personalother.contNameFname,
personalother.contNameLname, personalother.contStAddress,
personalother.contCity, personalother.contCountry, 
personalother.contTel, personalother.contRel, personalother.famBgndCh, 
personalother.famBgndChNo, personalother.famHhldNo,personalother.famHhldInc, 
personalother.genInfoPart, personalother.wrkExpJH1, personalother.wrkExpJH2,
rsonalother.wrkExpLJ,personalother.wrkExpPJName,personalother.wrkExpPJPhone,
personalother.wrkExpJNo, education.eduId, education.eduSchAtt,
education.eduExamBody1, education.eduExamLevel1, education.eduExamSubj1,
education.eduExamGrade1, education.eduExamBody2, education.eduExamLevel2,
education.eduExamSubj2, education.eduExamGrade2, education.eduExamBody3, 
education.eduExamLevel3, education.eduExamSubj3, education.eduExamGrade3, 
education.eduExamBody4, education.eduExamLevel4, education.eduExamSubj4, 
education.eduExamGrade4, education.eduExamBody5, education.eduExamLevel5, 
education.eduExamSubj5, education.eduExamGrade5, education.eduExamBody6,
education.eduExamLevel6, education.eduExamSubj6, education.eduExamGrade6,
education.eduExamBody7, education.eduExamLevel7, education.eduExamSubj7,
education.eduExamGrade7, education.eduExamBody8, education.eduExamLevel8,
education.eduExamSubj8, education.eduExamGrade8, geninfo.genInfoId, 
geninfo.genInfoName, stugeninfo.genInfoId, stugeninfo.stuId, 
stumarketing.mktgId, stumarketing.stuId, stuschatt.schAttId,
stuschatt.stuId, stuwrkexp.wrkExpId, stuwrkexp.stuId, stuwrkpay.wrkPayId,
stuwrkpay.stuId, school.schAttId, school.schAttName, bank.bankId,
student.verified, bank.bankId, courses.courseId, courses.occArea,
courses.courseName, courses.courseType, courses.courseLevel
FROM student, bank, centre, personalother, education, geninfo, 
stugeninfo, stumarketing, stuschatt, stuwrkexp, stuwrkpay,
school, courses,wrkexp,marketing
WHERE bank.bankid=student.bankId 
and education.eduid=student.eduid 
and personalother.contid=student.contid 
and centre.centreid=student.centreid 
and courses.courseid=student.courseid 
and student.stuid=stugeninfo.stuid 
and student.stuid=stuwrkpay.stuid 
and student.stuid=stuwrkexp.stuid 
and student.stuid=stumarketing.stuid 
and student.stuid=stuschatt.stuid 
and wrkexp.wrkexpid=stuwrkexp.wrkexpid
and marketing.mktgid=stumarketing.mktgid
and geninfo.geninfoid=stugeninfo.geninfoid 
and student.verified=0
```

Comment: Check your Join conditions. Also Joining 16 tables in single query is not a good idea IMO

Comment: Yes it is possible to generate queries using 16 (or more) tables, and for such queries to produce data. But we have zero knowledge of your tables/data and perhaps you could provide the query you are using now. Basically, right now there is no fuller answer to your inexact question.

Comment: can you explain,and is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: Note that any time you have enumerated column names, it's a sure sign that your schema is denormalised. Your education table is a classic case in point.

Comment: the education table all the enumerated fields represent the fields in a form we are trying to replicate, also i was brought in on the project after the fact and I had issues because there was no ERD and no proper normalization done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to join table one by one.

select * from table1 
inner join table 2 on (tablea.id = tableb.id)
where (condition)

if this works well than add another table.

select * from table1 
inner join table2 on (table1.id = table2.id)
inner join table3 on (next condition)
where (condition) and (add another condition here)

if this works well than add another table

When you fix your query, change * to the specific fields set you want to select.

This way you will see if it is possible to continue to add all your tables you want to join.

Comment: @DrewPierce - I liked it too +1

Comment: Thanks as usual for the help everyone especiallu user1551066, i tried your suggestion and was able to find where my query was bugging out.